# Adding System.Net.Http.dll reference to windows phone 8 project throwing error

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, dotnet-httpclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am beginer to windows phone 8 development. I want to use HttpClient in my app it throws an error to add namespace for that. I am unable to  include System.net.http.dll reference to my project when i tried to do that i got this error as shown in screenshot below

http://i60.tinypic.com/2mdj447.jpg

I am using visualstudio 2013 and .net 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a DLL built for the "big" .NET. Add the portable version using Nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
```

Comment: while i'm trying to run that command(Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http) i got this error"The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable."

Comment: maybe some Nuget outage, try again later or try using the GUI tool (right click on References and Manage Nuget Packages)